# Navbar fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar that has no border. I'd like to add a border on the navbar when it scrolls at a certain Y axis and then go back to the original navbar. At this point, I am using jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut and I can't get the navbar to work correctly. 
Here is my js for it.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
if (window.scrollY > 500) {

    $('.nav').fadeIn('slow');
}
 else {
     $('.nav').fadeOut();
 }
},false);
```

Here is my index.html

```
 <nav role="navigation" id="top-nav" class="navbar-fixed-top">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="nav1">
            <li role ="presentation"><h1>Modern Concepts</h1>
          <li role="presentation" class="first-Anchor"><a     href="#myAnchor">Inovate</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#myAnchorToo">Design</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Build</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Here is my css.

```
ul.nav {
    display: none;
    border: 3px solid black
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get pageOffset of the window to test where you are in the scroll...

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    if (window.pageYOffset > 500) {
      //do the magic
    } else {
      //go back to original state
    }
}, false);
```

Here is the working example with many different tweaks... Good luck:

http://jsfiddle.net/pu1yLe4u/2/

Comment: thank you for the fiddle. I think that maybe I'm not asking my question correctly bc the fadein and fadeOut is doing exactly what I already have. What I'm looking for is the nav to be there up top and then when I scroll down for it to have a border come on.

Comment: In your javascript code you can add CSS dynamically at certain point... Example: $('.nav').css('border', '3px solid black');

Comment: if i wanted to add a css transition would it be the same way like you had it in the fiddle. '(transition-timing-function', 'ease');

Answer (score 0):

What is the current result of the effect?

Just a friendly reminder: You are using jQuery, but you are also using the native methods (windows.addEventListener). It may be an idea to avoid a mixture and make use of the scroll-Event of jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/scroll/). Just for an uniform code style.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on not mixing up the native methods with jQuery. Right now, the outcome is that the navbar doesn't display at all in the beginning, and then when I scroll it shows up. What I'm hoping for is that the ul>li will show up without the border. And then when I scroll down the Y, the border will show.

Comment: Your target is to scroll only when you are below the 500 (px?) and otherwise, the navbar should be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but based on what you provide it looks like you are hiding the menu initially (display: none) and only displaying it after the user scrolls via fadeIn. So it's working as you asked.

Based on your other comments, it sounds like you don't want to fadeIn/fadeOut, but just change the styling (the border). If that is really what you want, then define a class for the border and use the scroll position to toggle that class.

Comment: Bobdye thank you. I think I made this harder then it was supposed to be.

Comment: window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    if (window.scrollY > 500) {
        $('.nav').toggleClass('#nav1');
    }
});